# having trouble with css loader with webpack 2

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am getting this error after my webpack comiples my jsx file. I am importing 2 stylesheets into my jsx. But this is the error that appears on my browser window.

`Module parse failed: C:\Users\pheon\Desktop\complete-intro-to-react\public\style.css Unexpected token (5:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Any help will be greatly apprecuated!

My webpack config file is as follow:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './js/ClientApp.js',
  devtool: 'eval',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/public/'
  },
  devServer: {
    publicPath: '/public/',
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json']
  },
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    reasons: true,
    chunks: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js'),
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              url: false
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

style.css :

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;;
}

html {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.app {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(/public/img/3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
}

.app > h1 {
  color: white;
}

.landing {
  background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, .7);
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.landing > h1 {
  color: #B10DC9;
  font-family: Skia;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.landing > input, .landing > form > input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.landing > form {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.landing > a {
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fafafa;
  border-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.landing > a:hover, .landing > a:focus {
  background-color: #666;
}

.landing > a:active {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  color: #333;
  border-color: #333;
}

.details, .search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, .8);
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

pre {
  text-align: left;
}

.search > div > a {
  width: 30%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 19.8%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.search > div > a {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 70%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: inherit;
  margin-bottom: inherit;;
  border: none;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.show-card {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2%;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 32%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 19.8%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.show-card:nth-child(3n), .search > div > a:nth-child(3n) > .show-card {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.show-card > img {
  width: 46%;
  float: left;
}

.show-card > div{
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 52%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.show-card > div > h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.show-card > div > h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.show-card > div > p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.search > header + div {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

header {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 8px 30px;
}

header > h1 {
  font-family: Skia;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #B10DC9;
  margin: 0;
}

header > h1 > a {
  color: #B10DC9;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header > h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

header > h2 > a {
  color: #aaa;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.details > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
}

.details > div > iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header > input {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 350px;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.details > section > img, .details > section > h3 {
  width: 8%;
}

.details > section > img[alt] {
  -webkit-animation: spin 4s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spin 4s infinite linear;
  animation: spin 4s infinite linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

.details > section > * {
  margin: 0 1%;
}

.details > section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.details > header + section {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Comment: The error is saying you have an unexpected token on line 5 of `style.css`. Update your question including this file.

Comment: @KeithA i added the style.css, but its saying that because web-pack cant seem to find my style-loader. so it does not know how to compile the stylesheet

Comment: Ok. For one on line 2 there is two semicolons at the end of the line: Change `box-sizing: border-box;;` to `box-sizing: border-box;`. Your webpack file looks file to me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found out if you are running web-pack dev server, you have to restart the server if you change your config file.